# Angular new Vite builder compilation error when using sass with @use statements

Tags: angular, sass, vite

Compilation error when trying to use Vite builder.

```
[ERROR] Can't find stylesheet to import.
@use 'src/styles/utils/mixins' as mixins;
src\app\app.component.scss 1:1 root stylesheet [plugin angular-sass]
```

[image]

Configs:
[image]

there was no issue with esbuild browser builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [a known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23698) with a new esbuild builder.

Sass by default is only able to resolve files relative to the containing file. In other cases it will fallback to resolve files based on the [loadPaths](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/options/#loadPaths)(`includePaths` previously).

Under Webpack these work because additional paths are added in sass-loader to the include paths https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/49a578a218574ddc92a597c7e365b6c21960717e/src/utils.js#L306-L322.

### There are two solutions

1. Use relative path
2. Configure `includePaths` in `angular.json`.

For **single project workspace**:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    ""
  ]
},
```

**Multi project workspace**:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "projects/<project-name>"
  ]
},
```